# UK general visitor visa refused for funds evidence?

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, proof-of-funds, visa-refusals

My visa was rejected because I failed to provide bank statements.
I'm a drop-out student and at present I don't work and I don't study, so I don't have any account balance.

I've mentioned in my application that I'm supported by my father.

I'm visiting the UK to visit my friend for 5 days. I have provided my friend's invitation letter, visa, passport and bank statements. I have provided my hotel booking also.

I have provided my father's income tax return documents. But I failed to provide his bank statements. If I provide bank statements will I get an entry clearance?

Answer (score 5):

As you noted, a requirement is proof of how you're going to fund yourself while there.

SO if you don't, you'll clearly get rejected. This is not a surprise.

For most people, they provide their own bank accounts with funds in there.  If you're using someone else's funds (eg your father), you need to provide proof of this.

As a result, you're going to probably have to provide a letter from your father (get it notarised too), and last 3 months bank statements from his account too.  It's not ideal, but you have to convince the UK government of your access to these funds before they'll approve you, there's no way around this.

Will you then get approved? Maybe. They may fail you on something else.  This is why it's VERY, VERY important to read and re-read and make sure you've met all the requirements that are listed clearly on the application.  It sounds like last time, you chose to ignore the requirement for the bank statements - basically, you can't do this. You need to meet ALL criteria required in order to be approved.

Comment: The OP could get a joint bank account with his father.  That might make things a bit more straightforward.

Comment: The greater problem is probably that if the OP is a young person who neither has a job nor is a student, it will be a challenge to convince a consular officer that they have a motivation to return home -- even if the _formal_ requirements for the visa application are satisfied.

Comment: @HenningMakholm indeed, wuich is why I emphasized meeting all requirements in the final paragraph.

Comment: @MarkMayo, his father's bank statements do not show that the funds are available to the OP. The app will most likely fail on that ground.

Comment: @GayotFow indeed, so like I said, you'd need to provide a notarised letter, no? As evidence of this connection. The onus is still on the OP to show evidence.

Comment: @MarkMayo, he needs to show his own bank statements :)

Answer (score -2):

From his position of thought and like the advise above stated, he need to provide his own personal Bank statement with funds to cover his flight ticket for the trip and his living cost for the duration of stay. That what i did for my self and my Dad and visa was approved.
If he is declaring his father as sponsor, he must do likewise in his name and the amount for the trip reflecting in the account in bits and pieces not in lump sum.